# C3X Polling Strategy - Fewest Answered

Tags: pbx, call-manager

I've been playing around with a 3CX PBX system and have been trying to alter a call queue so that members of staff that have had the fewest calls will get called first.

So I have set the call queues polling strategy to "Fewest Answered" however our newest member of staff is complainning that she is now receiving all calls rather then been spread out over the team equally.

My question is what time period is the "Fewest Answered" covering. Is it looking for the fewest answered extension from the whole time the PBX has been running or for that day etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the call statistics for the queue will do it, can also configure it to be done on a schedule.

[image]